# QuantLib: How to iterate over Cashflows in a Leg

Tags: programming, quantlib

I am looking for a way to obtain dates and amounts of each cashflow in a leg, without having to pop the cashflows out of the leg, like this

```
for i in range(leg.size()):
    x=leg.pop()
    print(x.date(), x.amount())
```

Comment: This is probably better suited for Stack Overflow

Comment: Questions about the QuantLib API (or similar) are fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

A leg is just a list of cashflows:

```python
for c in leg:
    print(c.date(), c.amount())
```